# Colorama green and yellow does not work

Tags: python, python-3.6, colorama

```
from colorama import Fore, init, Style

init(convert=True)

print(Fore.GREEN + "Green")
print(Fore.YELLOW + "Yellow")
print(Fore.RED + "Red")
print(Fore.BLACK + "Black")
print(Fore.BLUE + "Blue")
print(Fore.CYAN + "Cyan")

print(Style.RESET_ALL + '')

input()
```

[image: Output]

What can I do to fix it?
I am using windows 10

Comment: This is very strange. Have you tried putting the green and yellow lines after, say, the red and black ones ?

Comment: Yes I try that but nothing...

Comment: thats strange, can i ask what IDE you are using? and if you run in console does it work?

Comment: When I run it with cmd like this "python my_program.py enter" it works perfect. But when i double click on the file I have the same issue... Has something to do with the python python launcher...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that running in CMD works perfectly try using this peice of code, I had a similar issue when I was using colorama. It will force the program to open in CMD which will hopefully fix your error.

```
if "started_with_prompt" not in sys.argv:
    cmd = 'cmd /C "'+sys.executable+' '+" ".join(sys.argv)+' started_with_prompt"'
    os.system(cmd)
    sys.exit()
```